# Python call boost .so file Library not loaded Error

Tags: python, c++, boost

I have a cpp project and I use boot to create a python interface to call the C++ functions with python3. I having trouble with importing it with python. If the project format is :

```
-project:
    |_ CppProj:
        |_ __init__.py
        |_ Makefile
        |_ cppFunctions.hpp
        |_ cppFunctions.cpp
        |_ cppFunctions.so
        |_ cppFunctions.o
        |_ PythonCallCppInside.py
    
    |_ pythonCallCppOutside.py
```

I add __init__.py to the cpp directory so that I can reference the directory from python but I'm not sure if that's a right way to do it.

PythonCallCppInside.py is a simple:

```
import cppFunctions
```

and pythonCallCppOutside.py is:

```
from .CppProj import cppFunctions
```

PythonCallCppInside can do the import and more (ie, call the function, transfer data, ...). However, pythonCallCppOutside.py gives me the following error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/path/CppProj/cppFunctions.so, 2): Library not loaded: cppFunctions.o
Referenced from: /path/CppProj/cppFunctions.so
Reason: image not found
```

I have tried adding :

```
import sys
sys.path.append('CppProj')
```

But that didn't work either. Same error as above.

I'm not sure why this error happens and it might be a very dumb mistake but I need to be able to call this .so file from outside of the directory but I currently can't.

Any help is appreciated.

Update: Thanks to jackw11111, the solution is found in the formation of the make file.

```
cppFunction.so: cppFunction.o

    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) cppFunction.o -shared -o cppFunction.so -L$(BOOST_LIB) -$(BOOST) -L$(LIBPYTHON_PATH) -lpython$(PYTHON_VERSION_FINAL)
```

```
cppFunction.o: cppFunction.cpp

    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c cppFunction.cpp -fPIC  -I$(PYTHON_INCLUDE) -I$(BOOST_INC) -L$(BOOST_LIB) -$(BOOST) -L$(LIBPYTHON_PATH) -lpython$(PYTHON_VERSION_FINAL) -o cppFunction.o
```

Seems to work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you `cd` inside of `CppProj` and run iPython with `python` and then `import cppFunctions` does it import with no errors? and have you tried using the absolute path with `sys.path.append()`? Also, what command are you using to compile your c++ file to .so?

Comment: yes when I cd in and run the python file in CppProj it runs fine.

Comment: What about the absolute path?

Comment: Yes when I cd in and run the python file in CppProj it runs fine.
Using absolute path with sys.path.append() did not work.
These are the flags I use:
-lm -pthread -O3 -std=c++11 -march=native -Wall -funroll-loops -Wno-unused-result
and I also have my boost and python libraries to make the .o and then the .so file.

Sorry the last comment didn't save properly. My bad.

Comment: What about just `from CppProj import cppFunctions`? Apologies for all the questions, I am still trying to reproduce it...

Comment: Oh no of course. Thank you very much for all the help. I appreciate it.

Unfortunately that did not seems to work either. I even tried to import PythonCallCppInside.py from pythonCallCppOutside.py and it didn't work.

I also checked to see if any of the flags in the build are important but (I removed and added them back) but the problem persisted.

Answer (score 0):

The import statement calls `dlopen()` using its absolute path (`dlopen(/path/CppProj/cppFunctions.so, 2)`, which works fine. It looks like you are trying to load a library which loads another (`cppFunctions.o`) and so you've lost control of specifying where the library lives with its absolute path. It is searching for `cppFunctions.o` instead of `/path/CppProj/cppFunctions.o` which is why it can't find it, because there is no `cppFunctions.o` in the folder that you are calling the python script from. So you will need to either move the .o file into the directory where you call the python script, or you need to call your python script from where the .o file is in the file tree.

Another option would be to eliminate the dependency of the .so file on the .o file, which should solve the issue.

there shouldn't be a dependency from the .so file for the .o file except in creating it, after that it shouldn't need it, so I am not sure what is going on there (are you build the .so file with `-fPIC`?). So you should make sure that you compile the `.o` file with the `-fPIC` flag which stands for Position Independent Code, and allows for proper execution regardless of its absolute address:

```
g++ cppFunctions.cpp -c -fPIC ... -o cppFunctions.o

g++ cppFunctions.o ... -shared -o cppFunctions.so -lpython -lboost_python ...
```

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. I used to have the -fPIC but I didn't have the -c and also had the -shared in the wrong place.
1: Added -c to the making of .o
2: Added -shared to the making of .so instead of the making of .o
These seem to have done the trick. I will add the make file lines that worked bellow as well.